# Open source web map client with time sliders using WMS source

Tags: geoserver, wms, fields-attributes, time, wms-time

I have a web map service (WMS on geoserver). It has [a current visualization](http://havmiljo.no/Home/SprakValg?lang=en-US&returnUrl=%2FKart) which is decent. The data is divided into months currently using tabs. I would like to visualize the data using an open source based web map client with a time slider.

I have seen some examples around, but I am looking for a generic solution where I basically can change background layers (also WMS), source wms and relevant attributes. This to be able to experiment further with the solution. The wms time layer (wms-t) should not change the background wms-layers. They should remain controlled by a config-file or interactive selection interface not related to the time slider.

The current services can be accessed through the wms time parameter:

[time=2014-1](http://wms.miljodirektoratet.no/geoserver/kystinfo/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=kystinfo:fugl&styles=&time=2014-1&bbox=-330000.0,6300000.0,1390000.0,9020000.0&width=323&height=512&srs=EPSG:32633&format=application/openlayers)
[time=2014-5](http://wms.miljodirektoratet.no/geoserver/kystinfo/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=kystinfo:fugl&styles=&time=2014-5&bbox=-330000.0,6300000.0,1390000.0,9020000.0&width=323&height=512&srs=EPSG:32633&format=application/openlayers)
etc

It should be possible for the user to set min/max values and intervals, or the client should be able to guess this by itself based on the getcapabilities-info.

ESRI or other commercial (closed source) solutions are not possible options for this question.

Comment: Do you need the solution to be compatible with your actual visualization or are you looking for a possible separate web map client? I used leaflet and a plugin to do something similar (Plugin "TimeSlider")

Comment: Completely outside the current one. Looking for a quick and dirty proof of concept to prototype new functionality.

Comment: "I have seen some examples around, but I am looking for a generic solution where I basically can change background layers (also WMS), source wms and relevant attributes."

So you want some map contexts relative to time values? For example background1, wms1, wms2 relative to month1 and background2, wms1, wms3 relative to month2. Or you will have all these layers with time dimension?

Comment: Nicolas, I have made some changes to the question. But your assumption is wrong. This required solution should be focused on one wms-layer shifting according to a time slider along the dates presented in the getcapabilities info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know any web client with an out of the box time slider for WMS-T layers. WMS dimension is strangely a property of the WMS protocol that is lacking in many tools I used.

I developed a solution to handle all dimensions (time and others) based on OpenLayers.
You can find it here : [WMS dimension example](http://cartographie.observatoire-environnement.org/visualiseur/?zoom=1&lat=6569829.48709&lon=456652.5756&idlyr=12082)

The layer in this example is defined in Mapserver with a default value (2013) and all proposed values (2000 to 2013).

When you click the filter icon at right a GetCapabilities request is sent and time values are then parsed in the XML to be proposed in the HTML drop-down list. You'll see in the code that we get a cached version of the GetCapabilities request for performance reason.

Later I'll display a jQueryUI calendar or a jQueryUI slider adapted to handle time for WMS-T layers.

So you can see that with OpenLayers and few lines of code you can get what you need. Hope it helps!

Comment: This answer is the closest one to an answer. If you manage to get a stripped down version of the client with a settings file/documentation it would be a good start. Adding a jQueryUI slider will bring us all the way.Saw your answer too late to award the bounty.

Comment: No it is not too late, it is awarded, thanks. I'll work on this feature next month and I'll edit my post to put the code.

Comment: What does the filter icon look like?

Comment: @DaveX it is a funnel : https://www.google.fr/search?q=entonnoir&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=951&site=webhp&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=eTKeVY_NKYPuUKSarZgL&ved=0CCAQsAQ
If you have a better idea for the filter icon I'll take it with pleasure :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can try this, http://lib.heron-mc.org/heron/1.0.3/examples/timeslider/index.html

[image]

This example has an amazing slider, Hope it meets all your requirements.

**UPDATE : Another Good Example:**

http://timemap.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.0.1/examples/kenya.html

[image]

Answer (score 2):

MapStore http://mapstore.geo-solutions.it/mapstore/ by GeoSolutions seems to have all the necessary components but perhaps they have not been packaged to a readily available installation package. From the demo gallery this weather portal has a time slider

http://geoportale.lamma.rete.toscana.it/MapStore/public/?locale=en

This one has calender views for selecting start and end dates

http://wiz.acque.net/portal/geonetwork?locale=en

And this one takes start and end dates from two sliders

http://cip-pakistan.geo-solutions.it/MapStore/

Answer (score 1):

Most time sliders aren't animating bitmap map images from a WMS or tile server. They are animating points that are being rendered as points (markers, SVG, Canvas) on the client side.

For an animation to be effective the client needs to have all of the data available before it begins the animation. If it has to go back to the server for anything it the delay of that request will ruin the effect.

The example given by Ashutosh above is the best you could hope for, where there is no animation.

If you are using points, then you can send all the coordinates to the client and have it loop over them for the time slider. Here's the gold standard of that method:

https://srogers.cartodb.com/viz/337d9194-6458-11e3-85b5-e5e70547d141/public_map